# nested checkbox inside 2 formarray - angular material

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, checkbox, angular-material, nested-loops

I am trying to do a nested checkbox with angular material, I use one formarray inside other, the first list (days) of checkboxes works fine (I think so) , but with the second list (turns) I have troubles, this check all  checkboxes a the same time instead one, I tried to use formControlName with ngModel but I was not able to resolve it.
this is my code where the problem is:

```html
<section class="section">
          <div formArrayName="dias" >
            <div *ngFor="let dia of diaFormArray.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i" class="dias" >
              <mat-checkbox  class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="this.diaFormArray.controls[i].value['dia'].checked"
              [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">{{this.diaFormArray.controls[i].value['dia'].nombre}}</mat-checkbox>

              <div formArrayName="turnos">
                <div *ngFor="let turno of getDiaTurnos(i).controls; let j=index"  >
                   <mat-checkbox class="example-margin"
              id="turno{{i}}-{{j}}"
              [(ngModel)]="getDiaTurnos(i).controls[j].value['turno'].checked"
                [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }">
              {{turnos[j].nombre}}
              </mat-checkbox>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <pre>{{form.value | json}}</pre>
        </section>
```

this is the imagen
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lmqJMuUMki1wCAe6ChurNXmOH646bPx3/view?usp=sharing

this all project

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w2kdcw?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

anyone knows how I can proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your point, but you're going the wrong way. Since you are using Reactive Forms, **stick to them** and avoid messing around with *ngModel* too.

I've forked your project and adjusted it, so it works as you need. Check it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-czixcv?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Also, I've added a feature that checks/unchecks all *turnos* checkboxes inside a *dia*, every time you press the *dia* checkbox.

```js
private setListeners(): void {
  this.diaFormArray.controls.forEach((diaGroup: FormGroup) => {
    diaGroup.controls['checked'].valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      (
        (diaGroup.controls['turnos'] as FormArray).controls as FormGroup[]
      ).forEach((turnoGroup: FormGroup) => {
        turnoGroup.controls['checked'].setValue(value);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Ideally, you'll unsubscribe to this *valueChanges* subscriptions when the component is destroyed.

Comment: thanks, it works, I will follow you advice.

Comment: You're welcome! If you find it's the right answer, please mark it as the accepted one so others can benefit from it too.